# Angular2 animations(transform) can't work on iphone 6s

Tags: angular, animation

I want to use Angular2's Animation to implement an animation like this:

```js
transition('out => arise', [
    style({
        'transform': 'translateY(-50px)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(-50px)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateY(-50px)'
         }),
    animate('2000ms ease-in-out', style({
        'transform': 'translateY(0)',
        '-webkit-transform':'translateY(0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateY(0)'
    }))
])
```

as a result, Android and browser work good,but can't work on iPhone 6s.Any idea why it´s not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular animations use  web animations api. safari does not support it.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html
http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation

You can add polyfill to get it working

https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js